# Why doesn't this script end in infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to understand a code I found on the internet. I dont't understand in the while loop, why it is not an infinite loop. If change the `calculator.appendChild` in it to e.g. `console.log` it runs forever.

```
 window.location.hash = 1;
 var calculator = document.createElement("div");
 calculator.id = "height-calculator";
 while (document.body.firstChild) {
    calculator.appendChild(document.body.firstChild);
 }
 document.body.appendChild(calculator);
 document.title = calculator.clientHeight;
```

Basically there is always a first child in a non-empty site, so the condition is always true. Can someone explain why this way it doesn't run forever?

Comment: the `calculator` element is outside the dom, and the while loop simply moves over all children of `body` to `calculator`, so at some point, `body` will be empty and the loop ends. The key here I guess is that `calculator` is not itself a child of `body` during the loop.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A element can only be child of **one** other element.

```
calculator.appendChild(document.body.firstChild);
```

As soon as you attach `document.body.firstChild` to your calculator, it automatically *detaches* from body, so body will eventually run out of children.

Comment: But wouldnt there be another firstChild? not the same as earlier but what was next in line will become the firstChild now..wouldnt it?

Comment: `But wouldnt there be another firstChild?  not the same as earlier but what was next in line will become the firstChild now..wouldnt it?` It would, and then the loop runs again and takes this child as well, until it has no more children.

Comment: So basically the appendChild removes the element from the body, and adds it to the calculator? I thought it clones it

Comment: No it _steals_ the original. If you clone the node with `cloneNode` it would loop forever (or rather, until it runs out of memory).

Answer (score 1):

So process happens in 3 simple steps:

1. `var calculator = document.createElement("div");` this line creates a `div` **OUTSIDE** of the `body` in the DOM
2. Then the loop moves all the children of `body` into the `calculator` which eventually ends unless `body` has infinite children which is not possible.
3. `document.body.appendChild(calculator);` moves the `calculator` under `body`

So basically there are two major entities `body` and `calculator`, script moves all the children of `body` to `calculator` and then it moves `calculator` to `body`.

In other words script converts all children of `body` to the `grandchildren` of `body` and the only child of `body` becomes the `calculator`

I know I wrote too much but I myself understood it after a while, reading other comments and answers so I just wanted to leave it here for myself for future and for anyone else who needs more explanation to get it LOL